# PHP - Dynamically changing the URL, Error ID Not found

Tags: php, dynamic, pdo

New to php and decided to build a little template to display some fake content from a database. The goal is:

- loop through the DB, print the items,
- wrap them each in a link to the same page (in this case, `details.php`)
- use a `GET` (`details.php?id`) to put the id column of the DB.

I've got the printing/looping happening, and the linking but I'm running into a strange problem. When I try to echo out the ID, I get the following error: "Notice Undefined index: id in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/arrayTest/index.php** on line...". When I use another any other column from the DB, it echos properly. What am I missing?

**Query:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT firstName FROM userNames';
$query = $dbh->query($sql);
```

**PHP Page:**

```
    <h1>Names of People</h1>
<?php
    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 'Found some shit';
        foreach($query as $row) { ?>    

            <p><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['firstName']; ?></a></p>

<?php } } ?>
```

**DB Screen shot attached**[image: amic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM userNames';
```

You don't have the id because you are only selecting the `firstName`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use id in your query modify your query as

$sql = 'SELECT id,firstName FROM userNames';